# SearchBar With Scope Filter Inside of Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I am trying to achieve this but with the searchbar in my header

I am adding a search bar as subview of a navigation bar. When I set the showScopeBar function to true it keeps overlapping and it appears behind the search bar. I have tried making the height of the navigation bar bigger but no use. Any advice on how to approach this? I don't want to have to add my search bar to my collection header view.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
 import FirebaseDatabase
 import FirebaseAuth

 class EventSearchController: UICollectionViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

//resue identifier for the cell that you are constructing
let cellId = "cellID"

//ui search bar that will allow you to type in text and filter out results
//most of the code here is straight forward 
//must set delegate to self to get control over certain aspects of search bar
lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let sb = UISearchBar()
    sb.placeholder = "Enter Event"
    sb.barTintColor = .gray
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 230, green: 230, blue: 230)
    sb.delegate = self
    return sb
}()



//detects when search bar text is done editing
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("Stopped Editing")
    print(searchBar.text)
    guard let searchText = searchBar.text else{
        return
    }
    let lowerText = searchText.lowercased()
    fetchEvents(searchString: lowerText)


}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    if searchBar.text?.isEmpty == true
    {
        filteredEvents.removeAll()
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //Changes the first responder to the search bar
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

// this function will detect change in the search bar and filter out the results returned based off what is entered in the search bar


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white

    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)

    let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar

    searchBar.anchor(top: navBar?.topAnchor, left: navBar?.leftAnchor, bottom: navBar?.bottomAnchor, right: navBar?.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 8, width: 0, height: 0)
    //will register a cell to the screen
    //notice the EventSearchCell that is one of the parameters
    //that is there so it creates the cell in the way that I want it to based off the EventSearchCell Swift File
 self.collectionView?.register(EventSearchCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag

}
//two arrays both of type Event
//one for appending the results of the database search
//one for grabbing the results of the search bar
var filteredEvents = [Event]()
var eventsArray = [Event]()
fileprivate func fetchEvents(searchString: String){
    print("Fetching events....")
    //create a reference to the location in the database that you want to pull from and observe the value there
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("events")
    // this will retur a snapshot with all the data at that location in the database and cast the results as a dictionary for later use
    let endString = searchString + "\\uf8ff"
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "event:name").queryStarting(atValue: searchString).queryEnding(atValue: endString)
    print(query)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else{
            print(snapshot.value)
            return
        }
        print(snapshot.value)
        dictionary.forEach({ (key,value) in
            print(key,value)
            guard let eventDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else{
                return
            }
            let events = Event(currentEventKey: key, dictionary:eventDictionary)

            let filteredEvents = self.eventsArray.filter { (event) -> Bool in
                return event.currentEventKey == events.currentEventKey
            }

            if filteredEvents.count == 0 {
                //append
                self.eventsArray.append(events)
            }


            self.filteredEvents = self.eventsArray.filter { (event) -> Bool in
                return event.currentEventName.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased())

            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }


        })


    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch event data", err)
    }



}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //make sure that the screen is loaded with the proper number of cells when you first go to the screen
    return filteredEvents.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    searchBar.isHidden = true
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
  let event = filteredEvents[indexPath.item]
    print(event.currentEventKey)
    let currentEventDetailController = EventDetailViewController()
    currentEventDetailController.eventImage = event.currentEventImage
    currentEventDetailController.eventName = event.currentEventName
    currentEventDetailController.eventDescription = event.currentEventDescription
    currentEventDetailController.eventStreet = event.currentEventStreetAddress
    currentEventDetailController.eventCity = event.currentEventCity
    currentEventDetailController.eventState = event.currentEventState
    currentEventDetailController.eventZip = event.currentEventZip
    currentEventDetailController.eventKey = event.currentEventKey

    self.filteredEvents.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
    self.eventsArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(currentEventDetailController, animated: true)
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    searchBar.text = ""
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    filteredEvents.removeAll()
    searchBar.isHidden = false
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //creates a cell and cast it as the Appropriate type
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! EventSearchCell
    cell.event = filteredEvents[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

//constrols size of the cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 66)
}

}
```

Comment: Could you please share an image of what you want to achieve? May be we can find another solution.

Comment: @TungFam see edits

Comment: @TungFam see edits

Comment: sorry, can you please show the issue that you face?

Comment: the issue is that in my current code it shows up behind the search bar not below it

Comment: i read everything again but sorry can't get it. what shows up behind the search bar? and where you want it to be?

Comment: the thing that shows up behind the searchbar is the preinstalled segmented control that comes witha search bar. we want it to appear below it. It is rendering itself behind the searchbar instead